# How to get SharedAccessKey for Azure IoT-Hub

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

Does anyone know how to create SharedAccessKey for azure IoT hub?
I would like to create a default configuration with hostname xxxxx.azure-devices.net and dynamically set the deviceId. How to create with this both parameters the required SharedAccessKey?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_cli_iot_ext_az_iot_hub_generate_sas_token

Comment: @silent thank you! I'm looking for a solution inside my code where i starting using the connection. Your example shown it by using the CLI in azure.

Comment: well, what information do you have available in your code? the device symmetric key or the IoT Hub owner key (or another key with registry permissions)?

Comment: @DavidStania have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security and select your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the shared access signature using the device sdk or the service sdk.
On service sdk side, you can create a generic shared access signature i.e. with resourceuri as `{IoT hub name}.azure-devices.net/devices`. Check relevant link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#use-security-tokens-from-service-components).

On device sdk side, you can use the below image algorithm and generate the signature and use it in the code to connect to IoT Hub. For example, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_with_sas.js#L15) is NodeJS code for device sdk which uses SAS. You can find similar examples in C# too.

[image]

So, in the above image u can use policy as `iothubowner` which has all relevant permissions and with that you can fetch/update/add any device information.